# React Native for Android ScrollView inside custom layout

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having trouble wrapping a custom Android layout with React Native and getting a nested `ScrollView` to scroll. The layout is Android's [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

It looks like touches are passing through the layout just fine -- I have touchable content within the `ScrollView` that I can press. But for some reason the scrolling action isn't getting passed on. Incidentally, I've tested with a `FrameLayout` as well as the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and it doesn't work with that one either.

### Java ViewGroupManager

```
public class ReactSwipeRefreshLayoutManager extends ViewGroupManager<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTSwipeRefreshLayout";

    @UIProp(UIProp.Type.STRING)
    public static final String PROP_COLOR = "color";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactSwipeRefreshLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
        return new ReactSwipeRefreshLayout(themedReactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateView(SwipeRefreshLayout layout, CatalystStylesDiffMap props) {
//      BaseViewPropertyApplicator.applyCommonViewProperties(layout, props);
        layout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(props.getString(PROP_COLOR)));
    }
}
```

### React Native layout:

```
  <SwipeRefresh color='blue'>
    <ScrollView>
        {/* More stuff goes here... */}
    </ScrollView>
  </SwipeRefresh>
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing a lot here. Isn't there a JSX component to it? Anyway, if you figure it out, maybe you could add it to https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-refreshable-listview

Comment: Yeah, I haven't added the JSX component, the ReactPackage where it's exported, etc, just for brevity's sake. I'm fairly certain that the problem isn't in those omitted components though because they're practically just copy-paste from the docs and there's no logic in them, and I know the native component is getting mounted correctly (the pull-down gesture correctly exposes the loading spinner).